# overflow: hidden on table causes bottom and right border to dissappear

Tags: html, css

As the title says my table border is being cut off on my table when using overflow: hidden. Please see code below for example.

```
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>

    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>header 1</th>
                    <th>header 2</th>
                    <th>header 3</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>side header</th>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>footer header</th>
                    <td>footer 2</td>
                    <td>footer 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have simplified my example down the the bare minimum. I could lose the border-collapse style which would correct this, but I need that style. My code becomes to messy without it.

As an interim solution I have found that I can hack it using the css below, but I am not a hug fan of hacks!

```
.borderhack:after {
            content: '\00a0';
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid black;
            left: -2px;
            top: -2px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -10;
        }

        table {
            position: relative;
        }
```

I would appreciate any explanations or better solutions to this. I am really interested to know why it's actually doing this after a days worth of investigation.

Thanks

Comment: As I said - "I have simplified my example down to the bare minimum" - this is just to demonstrate the bottom and right border disappearing.  Please see example to demonstrate how things could go wrong without border-collapse (and yes I know that you could manually set specific borders to get around this, but it can get messy with larger tables/examples). [Find example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_mes/myY7c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to skrivener and some further investigation I have managed to figure this out. See the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_mes/TasbZ/4/).

**Problem** - border collapsing not equal around table border:

```
.table1 {

    border          : 3px solid black;
    overflow        : hidden;
    border-collapse : collapse;
}
```

**Solution** - must not declare border width in `border` must do it using `border-width`:

```
.table2 {

    border          : solid black;
    overflow        : hidden;
    border-collapse : collapse;
    border-width    : 6px 7px 7px 6px;
}

th {

    border: 1px solid black;
}

th {

    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Problem:**

```
<table class="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>side header</th>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>footer header</th>
            <td>footer 2</td>
            <td>footer 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Solution:**

```
<table class="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>side header</th>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>footer header</th>
            <td>footer 2</td>
            <td>footer 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Skrivener:

> "The why of it happening, I think, is that when using the collapsed
>   border model of table borders the browser is trying to split the
>   border in the center. On a one-pixel outside border obviously that's
>   not possible, so the browser is using a full pixel width if top/left,
>   and nothing if bottom/right."

This let me to believe that perhaps if I just set the 4 borders setting `border-width` manually and added 1px to the right and the bottom, the rounding would work correctly. See the solution and you can update the borders to see it works correctly. Now no matter what you can have equal width outer borders as long as you add 1px to the right and bottom borders.

Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 6):

There are two quick solutions:

1. Use 2px border width.
2. Use outline instead of border.

Eg:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6NVtS/1/

The why of it happening, I think, is that when using the collapsed border model of table borders the browser is trying to split the border in the center. On a one-pixel outside border obviously that's not possible, so the browser is using a full pixel width if top/left, and nothing if bottom/right. This behavior might be somewhere in the standards, I didn't look that far. But inside this will correctly fill out the borders without doubling up width, it's just the combination of the outside and overflow:hidden that's presumably cropping the bottom and right, which the browser generates but are technically nudged a half-pixel to the right and thus are 'outside' the region of the element. I hope that makes sense. Outline is not cropped by the overflow - I'm not sure why, I wouldn't have predicted an exception.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders

Another solution might be to apply overflow to td and th instead of table, or check if you really need to set overflow at all.

Comment: I thought this was an answer to my prayers, but if you add borders to the inner cells say, the headers - the collapse does not take affect, so you have borders of different widths when you want them all to be identical. Please see examples below of the two solutions you provided. The cells should be collapsing to the outer border from my understanding.  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_mes/6NVtS/2/  - I updated the first example with an increased border so you can see the width is not equal all around the table. The borders to th will demonstrate that the borders are not collapsing correctly.Thx

Comment: Awesome I have figured it out thanks to you skrivener - the part about rounding in your post made me wonder if I just manually set all the borders and added 1px to the right and bottom - wouldn't the rounding then work correctly. Check out the [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_mes/TasbZ/3/) - now you can increase the table border (ensuring right and bottom border =+1px) without any discrepancies between borders sides. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in using `border-collapse` if there are no borders to collapse? Remove the `border-collapse` and you'll be fine.

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/86xST/

Comment: As I said - "I have simplified my example down to the bare minimum" - this is just to demonstrate the bottom and right border disappearing.  Feel free to add css for more border.

Comment: Can you explain why you need `overflow:hidden;`? This seems like an odd thing to do on a table.

Comment: Yes it is odd with out context I guess. I am creating a table that has hover rows and columns. I.e. they get highlighted when hovering over a cell. In order to get the columns highlighted you use a trick which you can find [here]http://blog.thinkingstiff.com/2012/06/26/highlight-table-column-on-hover-using-css/#comment-172 - if you don't use the overflow:hidden, the background will push out of the table which you don't want. Hope that explains why it's there. As I said there is only the bare minimum included so as not to clutter the code with unnecessary code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following
1. give margin to your table
2. User table-layout: fixed
3. set